# Rxjs: emit on condition: array attribute vs timer

Tags: javascript, rxjs

an invocation to the rxjs wizards, it is possible to get a flow like the following:

```
stream1: 1, 2, 3, ... //this stream interval can be paused
array: [{text: "hi", time: 2}, {text: "hi", time: 10}] // static array

emit when current stream1 value === array.time
```

I have tried with a combination of zip, iif, but did not succeed, so I would appreciate any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some observable source that emits a boolean to indicate whether the "timer" should be enabled or not, you can define your timer like this:

```js
const timer$ = enableTimer$.pipe(
  switchMap(isEnabled => isEnabled ? timer(0, 1000) : NEVER),
  scan(time => time + 1, 0)
);
```

This simply switches the source between a 1 second interval and an empty observable that never emits. `scan` is used to always emit the previously emitted value + 1.

Then, you can define your "array emits" by using `map` to return the search result of your array for an element with matching time.  We use `filter` to filter out `undefined` results (*where no match was found*):

```js
const arrayEmits$ = timer$.pipe(
  map(time => array.find(i => i.time === time)),
  filter(i => !!i)
);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67009984?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `delayWhen` operator to delay emissions from one observable like so

```js
import { from, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { delayWhen, find } from 'rxjs/operators';

// our stream observable - emits every 1000 ms
const stream1 = timer(0, 1000);

// our static array
const array = [{text: "hi", time: 2}, {text: "hi", time: 10}]

from(array)
    .pipe(
        delayWhen((arrVal) => interval.pipe(find(time => time === arrval.time)))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log)
```

`delayWhen` will delay items from the input observable (in this case, `from(array)`) until another observable (`interval.pipe(find(time => time === arrval.time)))` in this case) emits

[link to rxjs docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delayWhen)

[link to learnrxjs page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delaywhen)